# Will it be useful to upgrade from using testcafe open source to studio?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, web-testing

I have been coding tests in testcafe open source for months now and have many thousands of lines of self-built code using testcafe.

Will it be useful to upgrade to the studio version?

Some of my testing fails because the website I test have some very dynamic operations which cannot be tested with the testcafe I use. Will the recorder functionality of testcafe studio help for this?

Comment: Would you please clarify what you mean by 'very dynamic operations' so that I can better understand your requirements? Thank you in advance.

Comment: By this I mean that it is very difficult to create selectors for certain things. For example: selecting a menu item that pops open a selectra list that disappears as soon as the mouse is moved off. This means that using the console to find the selector for the selectra list that only shows once selected is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification.

Comment: If you are not sure - you can try it for 30 days. Also, there is an option to buy professional support, it might be valuable for you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your requirements, TestCafe Studio will definitely meet your requirements to auto-generate all proper web page selectors. Its [Visual Test Recorder](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400165/guides/record-tests) will automatically generate selectors for your actions.

Furthermore, the TestCafe Studio Test Editor allows you to [choose a different selector type](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/400407/guides/record-tests/element-selectors) from many auto-generated selectors, which will better meet your page design and architecture.

Also, TestCafe Studio is available with a free 30-day trial period. You can check it out for free and receive official DevExpress support during your trial period: https://www.devexpress.com/testcafestudio

Comment: I am busy using the trial version currently to evaluate if it will save time and thus be worth the cost. I am taking it through the items I have not been able to manually code tests for on our websites and so far it is not recording drag/drop very well but will see how it performs for the rest.

Comment: Is there way to convert a js test to the test in the suite? Currently (as far as I can see) once you create a recorded test, then edit it in the editor, you are stuck with the JS code, you cannot covert it back to the test format. Or am I wrong?

Comment: You are right - there is no way to convert a JavaScript test into the Studio format test and we don't plan to introduce this functionality. The reason is that when you edit your JavaScript test, you can write any custom JavaScript code. The TestCafe file format may not support your custom JavaScript code. Converting it back to the TestCafe format may lead to unexpected behavior because your custom code will likely be lost during the conversion.